# Intellij: Import existing maven settings in new window

Tags: intellij-idea

I checked out new project through git and opened that project in new window, in new window I have to set same maven project settings again in new window.
so is there any way in Intellij to import existing maven settings in new window ?

Comment: What specific settings do you mean?

Comment: like importing maven settings.xml file path & JDK version.

Comment: File | Other Settings | Settings for New Projects.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a project open it as below
[image]

Then select your project and after that select the option maven as below
[image]

Finally remember to select the correct maven directory and maven settings file as below
[image]

This is the correct way to import a maven project. If you import it like this, you won't have to change your setting again

Comment: I followed File > New > Project from Version Control > Git

Comment: @user git support will be there even if you import it as a maven project like I have shown. Try that one :)